# Why can't we use "Local tag" & "Remote tag" to identify a dialogue?

Tags: sip, sip-server

A per the "RFC 3261 Session Initiation protocol", I have read that Call-ID, From and To tags are used to identify a "Dialog". Why we need Call-ID here? Why can't we identify a "Dialog" using "Local tag(i.e From tag)" and Remote tag(i.e To tag)? Anyway "Remote tag" is different over multiple clients, right?

Answer (score 2):

From rfc2543, the OLD SIP, you can find information on the FROM tag header [Section 6.21](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2543#section-6.21)

> The From field MAY contain the "tag" parameter.

and information on the TO tag header [Section 6.37](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2543#section-6.37)

> The UAS or redirect server copies the To header field into its
> response, and MUST add a "tag" parameter if the request contained
> more than one Via header field.

Thus, both to and from tag can be missing with rfc2543 SIP Endpoints.

Thus, using the Call-ID+local-tag+remote-tag is mandatory to remain compatible
with older version of SIP where one or both of the tag !

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and time. Do you mean the end points which are compliant to rfc2543 spec may use Either From Tag or Call - ID?